# Adding Angular Universal with ASP.NET Core template in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular-universal

I have setup my Angular project as in the article provided by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022?

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add Angular Universal to the project and deploy on IIS.

Does anyone have experience with adding Angular Universal to ASP.NET Core preview template with .NET 7.0 ? Or have any guides on adding prerendering for angular in ASP.NET Core 7.0

**Update:**

i have tried using `dotnet new --install MintPlayer.AspNetCore.IdentityServer.Templates -> In VS -> create new project -> ASP.NET Core with Angular (SSR)`

Server Side Rendering for angular is all setup easily by using this amazing template

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253390/discussion-on-question-by-pjepsen-adding-angular-universal-with-asp-net-core-tem); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.